# How many mails is recommended to send and not be blacklisted by gmail, hotmail, or other common clients?

Tags: php, performance, smtp, newsletter, email-client

I have a website that eventually will notify members for upcoming events by email. Currenly there are 1500 registered users.

The idea is to create a script that will send 50 emails every 15 minutes using cronjobs (. Coding this script is not a problem, but **theorically**  I would like to know if email clients like gmail, hotmail or yahoo'd blacklist my ip/server because of amount of emails sent to them in a determinate lapse of time.

So, before to start with this system I could take the good practices to improve it and avoid since now, problems in the way.

Other facts:

- I have a vps
- SMTP will be the protocol
- Always a unique ip used

Comment: More important than volume considerations are having your mail server and VPS set up properly with reverse DNS entries and SPF records.

Comment: Let me investigate a little bit, because I do not have deep DNS technical knowledge.

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer. Focus in SPF record and actual email content and you'll be fine.

Comment: well, I did `host my-server-ip` and it printed some facts that do not match with my server name or ip adress. Looks like there is not reverse DNS config.

Comment: Forgive me, but this is why I wish email systems were set up so that to send anyone a message you would have to pay them an amount of their choosing. It wouldn't have to be much. If friends exchanged emails it would more or less cancel out, but it would stop these broadcast email blasts.

Answer (score 0):

Personal Gmail accounts are limited to 100 recipients per message.  Further details about these restrictions are available here:  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en

Yahoo's limit is 100 recipients per hour.